# How to get blank when the src in iframe is empty

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, iframe

i need to show an video (if present), when the user clicks on any one of the marker point on map. But now, it loads a main page, when i click on any one of the marker, Can anyine help me to solve this. I am not sure whether the html is correct or not.

HTML:

```
<iframe class="video" [src]="video" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Ts:

```
public video:any;

map.on("click", "points" + i, e => {
                    this.data = e.features[0].property;
                    this.data = JSON.parse(this.data.field);
                   if(this.mapData.video) {
                    that.video = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.data.video + '?autoplay=0&showinfo=0&loop=1&rel=0');
                   }
                  });
```

Comment: Should `if(this.mapData.video) {` be `if(this.data.video) {`? You test one value and then use another, but I think this may be a typo in your code example.

Comment: thanks for the response, i was getting error because, the video was undefined, i made it to work by giving condition,